# Validating extra input when using Uploadify

Tags: javascript, uploadify

Let me start by saying that I'm not a web developer (or any kind of developer), I'm just a lowly IT guy trying to do the work of 3 people :)  Thanks to some other posts here, I've been able to make it quite far, but I'm still missing one step.

I've added a textbox to my uploadify page so that users can enter in a username to be prepended to files that they upload. The prepending stuff is all in the uploadify.php. I have the text box data working with this code:

```
<form>
     <div id="queue"></div>
     <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" placeholder="Username" value="" /><br /><br />
     <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="false">
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php $timestamp = time();?>
                    $(function() {
                            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                            'formData'     : {
                                            'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                                            'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
                                            'UserName'  : $('#UserName').val()
                                            },
                            'queueSizeLimit' : 1,
                            'multi' : false,
                            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
                            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
                            'fileTypeExts' : '*.zip; *.txt',
                            'fileSizeLimit' : '1GB',
                            'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                                    $('#file_upload').uploadify("settings", "formData", {"UserName":$('#UserName').val()});
                                    console.log($("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "formdata"));
                            }
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

The last thing I want to do is validate that the UserName textbox has input, before actually sending the file.  I know I could do this easily on the server side PHP script, but I want to prevent the file from uploading if the user doesn't put something in the UserName text box.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Found the answer -- I was unsure if I could continue to add javascript inside the onUploadStart function, but it turns out I can.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that all I had to do was add the following inside the 'onUploadStart' function:

```
'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
    if( $('#UserName').val() == "")
    {
     alert ("Please enter a username");
     $('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel');
    }
    $('#file_upload').uploadify("settings", "formData", {"UserName":$('#UserName').val()});
```